# Vue.js cannot read property of null/undefined before it's assigned

Tags: vuejs2

I have a property that comes from `axios.get`.

It's defined in my `data` as `null` (or `''` or `[]`)

The `axios` call is in a `created` hook.

When the app is first loaded the console fills up with

```
 Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of null"
```

Of course, it actually shows the information correctly on the webpage, because `service` is not null, but this error is apparently thrown before axios fetches the data.

What's the best approach here?

Comment: Can you please share some code? It'll help us figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify your data as an empty object to avoid this error:

```
    data: {
       your_object: {}
   }
```

Where `your_object` is that object that will have service property when data is loaded.

(From my assumption, in axios.get promise function you do something like that:

```
your_object.service = result.data;
```

)

Answer (score 4):

add a `v-if` in the element where you are using the data `service`.

Here is an example:

`<label v-if="service">{{service}}</label>`

or use the parent if it's an array like this:

`<label v-if="parent">{{parent.service}}</label>`

Answer (score 3):

You can either initialize the data field with an empty, non null, value or guard the access using a v-if before the template using the property.